# Run static analysis tools in compile or package step in Maven2?

Tags: maven-2, static-analysis

I'm researching using Maven for my team, and one of my goals for the build is to have static analysis tools run for every build, and perhaps fail the build for certain severe errors.  However, in maven it seems that these are treated as reports and run on the `site` lifecycle.  This presents a couple of problems as we don't intend to use the site for most projects, and it requires an extra step (or at least additional phase) to get the static analysis.

Is there a way to run static analysis tools in maven-2 in the compile or package phase (or equivalent)?

Comment: Does it have to be maven 2? In maven 3, this can be done

Comment: @kostja Can be done in maven 2 as well.

Comment: I've self answered, but I'm open to better answers.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by configuring the plugin ([findbugs](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/index.html) for example) in the `<build>` section and configuring the `<phase>` in the `<executions>`:

```
<executions>
   <execution>
      <id>findbugs-run</id>
      <phase>process-classes</phase>
      <goals>
         <goal>check</goal>
      </goals>
   </execution>
</executions>
```

Comment: +1 Thats what I had in mind. Didn't know executions setting were available in v.2.